# How to pass argument to the state callback function in react

Tags: reactjs

Am try to pass the parameters to the state callback function, which has click event listener.

the parameters are not getting updated with the latest value, i always get the value which is set on first time click.

this is what i tried:

```
this.setState({ idx: i0 === this.state.idx ? null : i0 }, () => {
   document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu.bind(null, i0, event));
});

closeMenu(i0, event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({ idx: null }, () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
    });
  }
```

Am expecting the closeMenu function parameter i0 value should get always the latest value which is getting passed from parent function.

Comment: What do you mean by passing from parent functions, you mean as a props ?

Comment: Sorry yes props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points to consider. Why do you setting up listeners in callbacks to setState, setState is async, who can know what can happens in this scenario ? If you not denouncing you button click (or how you trigger this functionality) what if listener will be initialized up multiple times ? Another point, you doing this in callback to setState, what if component will be unmounted in this point ? This is clearly a possibility. I think the right choice will be to setup listener in componentDidMount and remove it in componentWillUnmount. So it should be something like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
}
```

One more point, to consume props in closeMenu or anywhere just you arrow functions like so :

```
 closeMenu =  event => {
     let i0 = this.props.i0;
     event.stopPropagation();
     ...
}
```

This will save you from passing additional parameter as it will bind function to component context and allow you to access props directly. If you elaborate a bit on what you trying to achieve, i can try to explain better.